# Summing even fibonacci numbers in lisp

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I've just started learning Lisp, and I'm working through some Project Euler problems. I'm stuck on the one where you sum the even Fibonacci numbers below a max number. The things I've tried follow. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627382/the-lisp-way-to-solve-fibonnaci?rq=1) but I'm still not sure why neither of my ways works!

```
CL-USER> (defun sum-even-fibs (max)
           (do ((curr 0 next)
                (next 1 (+ curr next))
                (sum  0 (if (evenp curr) (+ sum curr))))
               ((> max curr) sum)))
SUM-EVEN-FIBS
CL-USER> (sum-even-fibs 10)
0


CL-USER> (defun sum-even-fibs (max)
           (let ((sum 0))
             (do ((curr 0 next)
                  (next 1 (+ curr next)))
                 ((> max curr))
               (if (evenp curr) 
                   (setq sum (+ sum curr))))
             (format t "~d" sum)))
SUM-EVEN-FIBS
CL-USER> (sum-even-fibs 10)
0
NIL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're terminating the `do` loop as soon as `max` is greater than `sum`, which happens at the very first iteration.

After you switch that `>` to a `<`, though, you'll get an arithmetic error because you'll eventually bind `sum` to `nil` (when you update to `(if (evenp curr) (+ sum curr))` which is `nil` when `(evenp curr)` is false.  You need to provide the else-side as well;  it should be `sum`.

More importantly, `do` binds its values in parallel, not in sequence, which means that for the second iteration when you update `sum` to `(if (evenp curr) (+ sum curr) sum)`, you're using the `curr` and `sum` from the first iteration.  If that's not what you're intending, you should consider using `do*`.

#### Update

As per the [request in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329102/summing-even-fibonacci-numbers-in-lisp/16329421#comment25503055_16329421), here's a complete working version of the code.  Note that it is almost identical to the code in the question;  it only swaps the order of arguments to `>` so that termination is when the `curr`ent Fibonacci number is greater than the `max`imum value, and adds the else case to the `if` expression, so that when `(evenp curr)` is false, the value is `sum` is preserved.

```
(defun sum-even-fibs (max)
  (do ((curr 0 next)
       (next 1 (+ curr next))
       (sum 0 (if (evenp curr) (+ sum curr) sum)))
      ((> curr max) sum)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there would be an issue with evaluation sequence in the first iteration but I wanted to make sure the function would actually do something first.

Comment: As a lisp n00b, I'd love to see the correct code for this.  The problem I'm running into is: I can do a loop, I can do the if, but I'm getting stuck on how to (a) initialize sum to 0 and (b) display the result.  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie I've posted the modified code.  It's almost identical to the original, but with the changes that I mentioned.  The comment about `do/do*` was only cautionary;  for this problem `do` was right.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly 'better' version of the answer of arbautjc:

```
(loop for a = 0 then b and b = 1 then (+ a b) 
      while (< a 4000000) 
      when (evenp a) sum a)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you gain a better intuition for which looping structure to use in different situations (do, loop, dolist, dotimes, etc.) with more practice?

Comment: @lightlike - Yes. (Though for what it's worth, I find the answer is typically `loop`, sometimes `mapcar` and very occasionally `dolist`. YMMV, of course, but I haven't used `dotimes` or `do` in a very long time).

Answer (score 1):

The loop instruction has many nice features:

```
(loop with a = 0 and b = 1 
      while (< a 4000000) 
      when (evenp a)
      sum a
      do (psetf a b b (+ a b)))
```

See [reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) in Common Lisp HyperSpec